# Nuget keeps adding old and non existing assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, npgsql

I have a C# solution consisting of 5 projects. One of them is an interface to postgresql database using npgsql driver. I've upgraded npgsql to 4.1.3.1 using NuGet.
I ran into a problem when my tests failed. It turned out that the problem is missing assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe in version 4.0.6.0 which doesn't exist in my filesystem.
According to the specification of the current version of npgsql, it requires it to be in at least  version 4.6.0.
I found out that the version 4.0.6.0 is forced in app.config  section and is appended there every time I run *Update-Packeage -reinstall*.
Why does this happen?
I also ran 'Analyze Assembly Dependencies' tool and it shows that npgsql in version 4.1.3.1 requires System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe in version 4.0.6.0 but I'm not sure whether it reads it from the app.config or from npgsql.dll itself.
When I ran the same tool on npgsql.dll itself it shows references to old versions (see attached picture). What do I misunderstand?
[assembly analyze output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blVD8.png)

Comment: right; there's an important distinction between *package* version and *assembly* version; I suspect that 4.6.0 is the nuget *package* version; however, on net472, the *assembly* version is: not that - IIRC the **assembly** version is still 4.0.6.0 - it just needs an assembly-binding-redirect, probably `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0"/>`

Comment: unfortunately, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe is notoriously painful for assembly-binding on netfx when dealing with libraries that use netstandard; you might also find [this post](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/) useful - it even uses System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe for the worked example

Comment: We're looking into an issue with Npgsql 4.1.x and System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2677. This should be resolved soon.